# jxbrowser demo failed on linux64

Tags: jxbrowser

When i run jxbrowser demo. On window it run well but on linux 64 system i get following exception. this error not clear so i write full stack here.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserException: Failed to load 'about:blank' web page within 120 seconds.
>       at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.b(SourceFile:334)
>       at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.(SourceFile:248)
>       at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.(SourceFile:177)
>       at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.(SourceFile:144)
>       at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.(SourceFile:130)
>       at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.demo.TabFactory.createTab(TabFactory.java:32)

**Update**:
After some trying i found a solution.

> BrowserPreferences.setChromiumSwitches("--disable-gpu","--no-sandbox");

Comment: Hmm. Check if chromium process is running and not being blocked.

Comment: thanks you for your reply but i still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: To fix the issue, first the root cause of the issue must be determined. Please enable JxBrowser logging, run Demo and share log messages that will be printed into console output. The log messages should shed some light on the root cause.

Comment: You right @Vladimir. I just add option -Djxbrowser.logging.level=ALL to see full log. But now i can't reproduct this issue. I think you should add default level log INFO to run script on demo package. Thanks your team.

Comment: @LưuĐạtLong If you found the solution, post your own answer and accept it for anyone got the same issue as you. :)

Comment: @Càphêđen. I update this question with a solution for my case, please check it.

Comment: I mean you should answer your own question below and accept it, not just edit your question. :)

Comment: ok @Càphêđen. Im newbie on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Just add option -Djxbrowser.logging.level=ALL to find out cause.
In my case i just resolved it with chromnium params.

> BrowserPreferences.setChromiumSwitches("--disable-gpu","--no-sandbox");